# How do I resolve this python error with selenium in ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been running this script and it worked fine but today I stopped the vm abruptly ( the script wasn't running ) and now when I try to run the script I get this error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auto.py", line 18, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_location,chrome_options=options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in _init_
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in _init_
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot parse internal JSON template: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
```

I haven't change the code at all.

Can some1 help please ?
Thanks!

Comment: so you saying that your code used to work but it's not working anymore ???

Comment: yes, and I haven't changed anything in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this to your code (import)

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from seleniumwire import webdriver
```

And change this :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_location,chrome_options=options)
```

into this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Hope this will work for you!!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find the problem.

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/chromeUserData")
```

This was the problem, my guess was that some files didn't save properly when I ended the VM abruptly.
I cleared the folder and now it works.